# Line up the columns of nested table to parent

Tags: html, css

So I have a table like so,

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="6">My 6 headers</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
         <td colspan="6">My 6 inputs</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="3">Indent 3 columns</td>
         <td colspan="3">
             <table>
                 <tbody>
                     <tr>
                         <td>repeating column 1</td>
                         <td>repeating column 2</td>
                         <td>repeating column 3</td>
                     </tr>
                 </tbody>
             </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

My issue is that, `<td>repeating column 1</td>` lines up with `<td>My 4th input</td>` column, but `<td>repeating column 2</td>` starts immediately after `<td>repeating column 1</td>` isntead of lining up with `<td>My 5th input</td>`. How can I align them?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pL89ykLp/

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and share it here?

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. Form layout is still layout!

Comment: it's totally possible, but you'll need to calculate the size added by paddings, margins and borders, which will probably be better with JS or JQuery. However, like other people said, the best path would be to avoid tables and start clean with divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the a nested table in the last  tag. Change the second row to this:

```
  <tr>
     <td colspan="3">Indent 3 columns</td>
     <td>column 1</td>
     <td>repeating column 2 </td>
     <td>repeating column 3</td>
  </tr>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9ywaqf1L/

Comment: There is a need. It says repeating for a reason, it's in a for-loop. I guess I could have stated that, so my bad. I'll accept this answer I guess as it's closest to my solution. I previously required the table, but recently made a change where I make use of multiple tbody tags. With this change it allowed me to simply remove the nested table and move the looping rows to the regular body, similar to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible with nested tables unless you set the width to something fixed, and make pixel perfect corrections. **This approach is highly unmaintainable**.

Instead, don't use tables for layout, and use some proper semantic markup. What kind of semantic markup? That's hard to know without knowing the context of your application.